# Change concurrent limit in react native background downloader

Tags: android, react-native, download, limit

I used this module "react-native-background-downloader" to create a download queue. By default, there are four concurrent downloads, but I want my concurrent downloads to be limited to one and the next file start when previous file download is complete.

To do this, I changed the "RNBackgroundDownloaderModule.java" file in the Android folder of the module and set the value of ConcurrentLimit to one.

```
FetchConfiguration fetchConfiguration = new FetchConfiguration.Builder(this.getReactApplicationContext())
        .setDownloadConcurrentLimit(1)
        .setNamespace("RNBackgroundDownloader")
        .build();
```

My question is: Is there a better way to do this than not to change the files in the module and do it dynamically from JavaScript?

Comment: Even me too want to download files one after another. did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Due to [this issue](https://github.com/EkoLabs/react-native-background-downloader/issues/48) in Github, the concurrent download limit can be changed only on the Android side, and for this you can edit the "RNBackgroundDownloaderModule.java" file in the Android module folder and change the "setDownloadConcurrentLimit()" value as desired.

In [this fork](https://github.com/mahdi-sharifimehr/react-native-background-downloader), I set the download limit on Android to one. Thus, in the waiting queue, the download of the next file starts after the download of the previous file is completed.